# How can I format the output of the File.WriteTextAll function?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

For this project I'm taking the input of a SQL Database and placing it into a txt file for easy transferring and what not.

So far it works but I want to make it easier to read. As this app runs, it updates the file every 60 seconds. I would like to add headers to the columns so someone reading it can tell what each column represents.
I don't know how to add the headers so that new text added every refresh inserts below the header.

This is what I have so far

```vb
private void Output()
        {
            string createText = "";


            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, AlarmData> AlarmDataText in AlarmDictionary)
            {
                createText += FormatWidth(AlarmDataText.Value.eventSeverity, 8) + FormatWidth(AlarmDataText.Value.eventLastNotification.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"), 18) +
                FormatWidth(AlarmDataText.Value.eventFirstNotification.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"), 18) + FormatWidth(AlarmDataText.Value.deviceIP, 18) + 
                FormatWidth(AlarmDataText.Value.deviceInterface, 20) + AlarmDataText.Value.descriptionShort;
                createText += Environment.NewLine;
            }

            if (true)
            {

            }
            File.WriteAllText("C:\\Users\\%username%\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\NMS_Logger\\NMS_Logger\\bin\\Log.txt", createText);

        }//end Output()
```

This is a sample of how it comes out in the text file

```html
Major   2015-01-05 11:15  2014-11-11 09:55  10.10.10.1               apSysMgmtInet
Major   2015-01-05 11:15  2014-11-11 09:56  10.10.10.1               apSysMgmtInet
Major   2015-01-05 11:16  2014-11-13 12:35  10.10.10.1    bwCNAMS    C N A M Server 
Info    2015-01-05 11:17  2015-01-02 03:29  10.10.10.1               CIT Debug Trap 
Major   2015-01-05 11:15  2014-11-14 09:48  10.10.10.1    RAI        telicaT1Alarm 
Major   2015-01-05 11:17  2014-11-20 02:11  10.10.10.1               portErrorsExceeded 
Info    2015-01-05 11:15  2015-01-05 11:14  10.10.10.1    NORMAL     telicaT1Event 
Major   2015-01-05 11:15  2014-11-14 09:48  10.10.10.1    RAI        telicaT1Alarm 
Info    2015-01-05 11:15  2015-01-05 11:14  10.10.10.1    NORMAL     telicaT1Event 
Major   2015-01-05 11:17  2014-11-12 05:05  10.10.10.1               Error ENVMON
Info    2015-01-05 11:16  2014-12-03 15:43  10.10.10.1               Debug SEC
```

As you can see column labels would be nice.

Comment: You could UNION ALL with a SELECT of hard-coded column names.

Comment: Use `StringBuilder` instead of appending to a `String` in a loop - it's much faster.

Answer (score 2):

You could just append your column name on `createText` like this :

```
string createText = //just make sure that the column name doesn't exceed your padding width
        FormatWidth("Severity" 8) + 
        FormatWidth("LastNotification") +
        FormatWidth("FirstNotification", 18) + 
        FormatWidth("DeviceIP", 18) + 
        FormatWidth("DeviceInterface", 20) + 
        "DescriptionShort";

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, AlarmData> AlarmDataText in AlarmDictionary)
{
    createText += Environment.NewLine;
    createText += 
        FormatWidth(AlarmDataText.Value.eventSeverity, 8) + 
        FormatWidth(AlarmDataText.Value.eventLastNotification.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"), 18) +
        FormatWidth(AlarmDataText.Value.eventFirstNotification.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"), 18) + 
        FormatWidth(AlarmDataText.Value.deviceIP, 18) + 
        FormatWidth(AlarmDataText.Value.deviceInterface, 20) + 
        AlarmDataText.Value.descriptionShort;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Outside the foreach loop and after the statement  `string createText = "";` you can append suitable column names to `createText`. Instead of using a `String` try using `StringBuilder`

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with StringBuilder, I'll look into it. Thank you.